# Splash Screen Issue iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, splash-screen

I am using Launch screen in Xcode to do splash screen for my app.

There is only an image on splash screen, no API hit in background.
It is taking too long on the splash screen by which the time exceed of 20 Sec and app crashed there, I have checked it on device log as well.

Sometime it crashes and sometimes it runs but it always takes too long.
I am not able to move to next screen from there. And it shows a white screen before the splash screen for only iPhone 6 Plus (no white screen on other devices).

How to come out the white screen issue for iPhone 6 Plus and resolve the splash screen time long issue ?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        // self.prepareForContact()
        if let a: AnyObject = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("isFirstTime"))
        {
            if let a: AnyObject = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userid"))
            {
                self.createAppFromHomepage()
            }
        }
        else
        {
            self.createAppFromWelcomeScreen()
        }

        isAllImageDownloading = false
        // Save this data to hit friend service on login on every launch...
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("1", forKey: "hitFriendService")

        let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: CognitoRegionType, identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityPoolID)
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: DefaultServiceRegionType, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
        AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

        //print(credentialsProvider.secretKey)

        if let event_id: AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("eventId")
        {
            self.getEventDescription()
            self.uploadEventRemainingImages()
        }


        let session1 = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        session1.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.AllowBluetooth, error: nil)
        session1.setActive(true, error: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()


        let nsDocumentDirectory = NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory
        let nsUserDomainMask    = NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask
        if let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
        {
        if let dirPath = paths[0] as? String
        {
            self.excludeFromBackupToICloud(dirPath)
        }
        }

        if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {

            let types:UIUserNotificationType = (.Alert | .Badge | .Sound)
            let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)

            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
        else
        {
            // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
           // application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(.Alert | .Badge | .Sound)
        }

         if let isFirstTime: AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("isFirstTime")
         {
         }
        else
         {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
          //  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("1", forKey: "isFirstTime")
         }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: please share the appdelegate code

Comment: You mention "no background API", which would actually be a good thing to keep the UI responsive. There are a few calls that could exceed 20 seconds: `createAppFromHomepage`, `AWSServiceManager`, `uploadEventRemainingImages`, ...

Comment: AWSService manager is just for configuring and other methods alike createAppFromhomepage and uploadEventRemainingImages . These two calls only when i logged once into an app while my issue is that app crash on splash screen . I am not able to reach login screen so these two methods are not effecting it.

Comment: no not right now bcz performSelectoronmainthread is not in swift . In place of it timer used but timer not help me to come out of this issue.

Comment: Updated response with Objective-C. Try again!

Comment: My code is in swift . In swift there is no performselecteronmainthread, it is available in objective c only. In place of it timer can be used but timer can not help me in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You are being killed by the watchdog. Your app does not crash per say.

**Investigate**

Profile your app under *Instruments*: You will see right away what is taking so long.

**Fix**

Allow `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to return immediately. Factor out all the hard work in a separate method, which you can invoke like so:

**Swift**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.performSelectorOnMainThread("didFinishLaunching", withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: false)
    return true
}
```

and do the hard work after returning (next event loop)

```swift
func didFinishLaunching() {
    // time consuming work goes here
}
```

---

**Objective-C**

```m
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didFinishLaunching)
                       withObject:nil
                    waitUntilDone:NO];

- (void) didFinishLaunching {
    // time consuming work goes here
}
```

Comment: I would also suggest that OP consider use a background thread or process for any API work that takes place in the background. When the API work is finished, the background thread/process can notify the application's main thread.